# Trying Bitmap to convert on PDF file and try to save file on download directory of android

Tags: android

Tring Bitmap to convert On PDf File and try to save it download directory . Application run successfully but doesnt generate pdf and doesnt save anything. even doesnt showing any error in log. so what is the error on given code. Help me out please. Thanks in advance.

```
public void CreatePDF(View view) {
File file = getOutputFile();
if (file != null) {
    try {
        FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(file);
        PdfDocument pdfDocument = new PdfDocument();

        for (int i = 0; i < imageUris.size(); i++) {
            Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(imageUris.get(i).getPath());
            PdfDocument.PageInfo pageInfo = new PdfDocument.PageInfo.Builder(350, 500, (i + 1)).create();
            PdfDocument.Page page = pdfDocument.startPage(pageInfo);
            Canvas canvas = page.getCanvas();
            Paint paint = new Paint();
            paint.setColor(Color.BLUE);
            canvas.drawPaint(paint);
            canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, 0f, 0f, null);
            pdfDocument.finishPage(page);
            bitmap.recycle();
        }
        pdfDocument.writeTo(fileOutputStream);
        pdfDocument.close();

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
}

private File getOutputFile() {
File root = new File(this.getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS), "My PDF      Folder");

boolean isFolderCreated = true;

if (!root.exists()) {
    isFolderCreated = root.mkdir();
}

if (isFolderCreated) {
    String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss", Locale.US).format(new Date());
    String imageFileName = "PDF_" + timeStamp;

    return new File(root, imageFileName + ".pdf");
} else {
    Toast.makeText(this, "Folder is not created", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    return null;
  }
 }
}
```

If you want to look up whole code Link : https://github.com/KayesFahim/ScannerBuddy/

Comment: `Application run successfully` Impossible as your code does not even compile: `Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(imageUris.get(i).getPath());`

Answer (score 1):

**Possibility 1:**

If you don't have the permission, add it in `AndroidManifest.xml`:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

these permissions are also mentioned, but I you don't need them (as long as you don't use the internet or camera):

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
```

**Possibility 2:**

There sometimes is a glitch with the emulator that makes Toast-messages not show. Maybe try to throw an exception while testing.

**Possibility 3:**

Try

```
Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS);
```

directly at first.

Or maybe the emulator somehow doesn't have a download folder, in this case try

```
root.mkdirs();
```

**Possibility 4:**

What is imageUris and where are the bitmaps you want to save? Why do you want to decode a Stream if you already have a bitmap? Why are you looping?

Just directly use your bitmap, without a loop, and replace `350` with `bitmap.width()` and `bitmap.height()`.

Comment: image Uris is array list of image. I wan to convert arraylist of image to bitmap. Beacuse I know how to convert bitmap to Pdf. Thats why I tried to get image from image stream.

Comment: showing this : W/System: A resource failed to call close.

Comment: @AnoxSoftwareTechnology If you know how to convert a Bitmap to a Pdf-File, try to display the bitmaps that you load in an ImageView. This way you can see if they were loaded successfully! For example you could do if (i == 0) imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap) in your loop.